# How do I get the ImageView in front of CardView?

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I need to get the `ImageView` above in front of `Cardview`. When I make `CardView` color transparent, `ImageView` is at the front but `CardView` should be white.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Background -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cover"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingTop="240dp"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            card_view:contentPadding="16dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                ...

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|end"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_gallery"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/accent"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/accent"
            fab:fab_colorRipple="@android:color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            tools:src="@drawable/profile" />

    </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Add ImageView after closing tag of scrollbar..

Comment: What you are using as parent is FrameLayout, items added on top will be displayed on top.

Comment: @MohammedAtif for correction, Items you added last will be displayed on top/front layer in UI.

Comment: Your code already works as you want it to... I even tried your code, it works perfectly.

Comment: @KamranAhmed don't get confused with frame layout and relative layout. What you told holds good for relative layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Background -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cover"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="240dp"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cardViewId"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
                    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                    card_view:contentPadding="16dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|end"
                    android:layout_marginRight="32dp" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                android:scaleType="center"
                tools:src="@drawable/profile" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Hope this help you somehow....